# jQuery and HTML toggle buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have the following code:

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-link\" onclick=\"personchange('{$row['first_name']}')\">{$row['first_name']}</button>";
```

What I am trying to do is read all the names from the database and create a button for each name. When a user clicks on a name, I want to call the `personchange` Javascript function, which works, and add a class to the button that changes the way it looks (so that the user knows which name is currently selected). I know we have to use jQuery to add the class, but how do I know which button I selected in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to button on click like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm assuming that OP wants one name selected at a time, so there should also be an extra line: a `.removeClass('clicked')` on the currently selected button before the `addClass` is called ;)

Comment: @Nondeterministicnarwhal They would have to add `$('.btn').removeClass('clicked');` to the function passed to `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an id attribute on each button, and in the onclick() function you may add that id as a parameter. You can then access the button by its id.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're doing icky-inline JavaScript:

`onclick="personchange(...); this.className += ' clicked';"`